# Streaming Data to HDFS via webHDFS protocol

Tags: hadoop-streaming, webhdfs, knox-gateway

We like to  write a streaming data to HDFS using Webhdfs( https) protocol.
 Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  After acquiring the stream handle from CREATE/APPEND you have to set the connection to be chunked, using HttpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(CHUNK_SIZE)